# Implementing full access to data from each module in Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm bit of confused with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/). I'm trying to design application with next structure:

[image: Acces structure of application]

### config.js

module.export = {loaded: false};

### main.js

```
var $ = require("jquery");

$(document).ready(function(){
   var App = require("app.js");
   App.start();
});
```

### app.js

```
var TagsManager = require("./mng/tags"); 
var SettingsManager = require("./mng/settings");

function App(){
   var config = require("./config");
   this.tagsManager = new TagsManager();
   this.settingsManager = new SettingsManager();
   this.method = function(){
       // here i'm changing config json
       config.loaded = true;
   }

   this.method(); //writing from this to config
   this.tagsManager.method(); //writing from tags manager 

}

module.exports = new App();
```

### tags.js

In this module I need to get access config.

```
function TagsManager(){
    var config = require("./config");
    ...
    this.method = function(){
       config.newProp =  config.loaded ? "This is new property" : null; 
    }
    ...
}

module.exports = TagsManager();
```

If I'm including config as a module into each other module then in every module I can read and write into config, but when I need read from another module supposed changes in config then I don't see them. I mean that when in app.js I write to config property `config.loaded = true` and after it I call method in tags manager that writes `config.newProp = "This is new property"` if `config.loaded == true`, I see that in tags manager config looks like it was determined in config.js.

Solution to put config to `window` object looks pretty musch weird. Are there any other solutions? Or I just don't understand how to use Browserify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the Browserify workflow works. Requiring a module into a variable and then modifying it doesn't save the information in the file where it came from. Browserify basically concatenates all your modules into a single script, with a light wrapper to read `require` calls. But you're still working **in the browser**. A global object is the right approach. If you want to save the information permanently, then you'll need a cookie, or localStorage or a database.

Comment: I suspected it. Thank you for explaining.